# Adjust netplan yaml with sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, yaml

Here is our yaml:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.200.2.11/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 4.4.4.4
        search:
        - cybertax.live
  version: 2
```

I want to change the dns severs only.
From:

```
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 4.4.4.4
```

to:

```
        - 10.10.10.10
        - 10.10.10.11
```

How can I do this? Note: we cannot use or install `yq` so this needs to be done through sed or awk. Also, yes I know, this is not recommended, but its what needs to be done right now.

## What I have tried so far:

```
sed -i '/        addresses:/,/        search:/ s/^/# /' $netplan_yaml
sed -i '/      nameservers:/a\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ addresses:' $netplan_yaml
for i in ${!asar_dns[@]}; do
    sed -i "/        addresses:/a\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ - ${asar_dns[$i]}" $netplan_yaml
done
```

But this does three things wrong (that I can see).

1. It matches between `addresses` and `search` including the line wiht `addresses` and `search`. I only want what is AFTER addresses, and BEFORE search.
2. It puts the DNS addresses in the associative array between the older addresses that is commented out anywhere there is an "addresses". I dont want to do that on the commented out line.
3. i dont like how I have to use `\ \ \ \ \ \` would much rather use a `.*` if possible but also need to use the addresses in the associative array.

Comment: please update the question to show your attempts at using `sed` and `awk`, along with the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: will the ip addresses always be the same? ie, you're alwayts looking to replace `8.8.8.8` and `4.4.4.4`? replacements will always be `10.10.10.10` and `10.10.10.11`? or could any of these ip addresses vary over time?

Comment: could the source ip addresses (`8.8.8.8` and `4.4.4.4` in this case) show up elsewhere in the yaml where they should not be replaced?

Comment: IP addresses maybe anything, and any amount of dns server, cant rely on matching on `8.8.8.8` and/or `4.4.4.4`

Comment: Is an `ed` answer acceptable?

Comment: Sure if you have a solution that may work.

Comment: Use a YAML tool like `yq`; as you clearly already discovered, regex solutions tend to be extremely brittle.

Comment: I literally said in my post that I cannot use `yq`.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that both the script and the file in question does not have windows line endings see [are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

---

Now if `ed` is available/acceptable, with your given input.

Something like.

```
ed -s file.yaml <<-'EOF'
  H
  g/nameservers:/;/addresses:/;/search:/-s/[[:digit:].]\{1,\}/10.10.10.11/\
  -s/[[:digit:].]\{1,\}/10.10.10.10/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

Using variables for the values, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

dns1=10.10.10.10
dns2=10.10.10.11

ed -s file.yaml <<-EOF
  H
  g/nameservers:/;/addresses:/;/search:/-s/[[:digit:].]\{1,\}/$dns2/\\
  -s/[[:digit:].]\{1,\}/$dns1/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

The `file.yaml` with 4 ip addresses.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.200.2.11/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 4.4.4.4
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 3.3.3.3
        search:
        - cybertax.live
  version: 2
```

To delete the lines with ip addresses, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s file.yaml <<-EOF
  H
  g/nameservers:/;/addresses:/;/[[:digit:].]\{1,\}/;/search:/-d
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

Output

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.200.2.11/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        search:
        - cybertax.live
  version: 2
```

---

To delete all ip addresses and add/change two entries, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

dns1=10.10.10.10
dns2=10.10.10.11

ed -s file.yaml <<-EOF
  H
  g/nameservers:/;/addresses:/;/[[:digit:].]\{1,\}/;/search:/-d
  t.
  -1s/^\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1- $dns1/
  t.
  .s/^\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1- $dns2/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

Output

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 10.200.2.11/22
      gateway4: 10.200.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.10.10
        - 10.10.10.11
        search:
        - cybertax.live
  version: 2
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is required, ala `sed -i`
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

Comment: This work pretty well. Only one problem, which was not a main requirement of mine in the original post, what if the yaml has more than 2 addresses listed? Lets say there are 4 addresses. Running your script replaces the first two entries with "10.10.10.11" the third with "10.10.10.10" and the 4th with "10.10.10.11". Is there a way to modify your solution to wipe out all entries and only put the two dns servers listed?

Comment: @Dave, you could give the new edited answer a try.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, but now I am confused. when trying to run the commands all I get it `?` from ed. Even the early commands you shared. Do you know why that would be happening? how can even trouble shoot this `?` is not very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I found a very hacky solution but it works. Open for feedback.

```
netplan_yaml=/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
baddns="$(sed -n '/.*nameservers:/,/.*search:/p' /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml | grep -v 'nameservers\|addresses' | grep -v 'search' | grep -v 10.200 | awk '{print$2}')"
mapfile -t arr_baddns  <<<$baddns
for i in ${arr_baddns[@]}; do
    sed -i "/        - $i/s/^/#/g" $netplan_yaml
done
for i in ${!asar_dns[@]}; do
    sed -i "/        addresses:/a\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ - ${asar_dns[$i]}" $netplan_yaml
done
```